# texstudio: error while loading shared libraries: libpoppler-qt5.so.1

Tags: dpkg, shared-library, texlive

I installed `Texlive 2015`  on `Xubuntu 16.04` and then I downloaded `texmaker` `.deb` package and then I get this error:

```
texmaker: error while loading shared libraries: libpoppler-qt5.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

After That I installed `texstudio` with `.deb` package and:

```
texstudio: error while loading shared libraries: libpoppler-qt5.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How Can I Fix This?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to install another package (`blender`) with `apt-get` and fortunately `apt-get` guide me to the solution of broken libraries for last installed package with `dpkg`.
As `dpkg` messaged me I done this first:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

with no package in next to install keyword. After That problem of dependencies solved, and both `texmaker` and `texstudio` packages works now.